# Replace array values in javascript with .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets' Script editor, I want to **replace each of this table's values for numbers**, as follows:

```
"I like it" = 2
"I don't like it" = -1
"Haven't seen it" = 0   

+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|         |      User A     |     User B      |      User C     |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Movie 1 |    I like it    | I don't like it | Haven't seen it |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+   
| Movie 2 | Haven't seen it | Haven't seen it | I don't like it | 
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Movie 3 | Haven't seen it | I don't like it |    I Like it    |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I'm not sure whether I should use *array.map()* or *array.forEach()* but, in both cases, I can't figure out how to do the comparison of each cell with the strings in order to create the condition.

If possible, I'd prefer to avoid using two *for* loops, as I believe it must be possible with *array.map()* and that seems cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way using map():
(change sheet name and range to suit).

```
function stringToNumbers() {

var strings, numbers, range, data, ind;

strings = ['I like it', 'I don\'t like it', 'Haven\'t seen it'];
numbers = [2, -1, 0];
range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Sheet6')
    .getRange('B2:D6')
data = range.getValues()
    .map(function (r) {
        return r.map(function (el) {
            ind = strings.indexOf(el);
            return ind > -1 ? numbers[ind] : null;
        })
    })

Logger.log(data)
//range.setValues(data) //if you want to write the numbers back to the sheet, uncomment this line.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To translate all data in an array you'll probably want to use `Array.prototype.map()`. However, since your data structure i'm assuming is a nested array you may need to have a combo of `forEach` and `map`:

```
var arr = [['I like it', 'I don't like it', 'Haven't seen it'],[//etc]];

function stringToNumber(str) {
  var num;
  if (str === "I like it") {
    num = 2;
  } else if (str === "I don't like it") {
    num = -1;
  } else if (str === "Haven't seen it") {
    num = 0;
  }
  return num;
}

function mapRow(row) {
  return row.map(stringToNumber);
}

arr.forEach(mapRow)
```

Comment: Thank you hackerrdave. Though I prefered the other solution since it doesn't require so many else if statements.

Comment: Yea i prefer the other solution as well! haha